# Can I convert any grammar to an operator precedence grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction

Any grammar can I implement by operator precedence parsing?

Comment: This sounds like homework, because if you were really interested in this you would know the answer.

Comment: Are you asking if you can change the operator precedence?  The more I read your "question" the more my internal grammar-parser is beaten like an unwanted step-child.

Comment: can i implement if else statement by operator precedence parsing? if yes how?

Comment: Still not clear. Are you saying that, given a grammar which has arithmetic precedence (although this need be specified outside the grammar), can you convert it into a form where you obtain the same grammar with operator precedence observed, but no need for precedence/association rules? If so, then the answer is yes.

Comment: i have implemented arithmetic precedence.i need to implement if else statement,loops...etc .i want to know can i implement it by operator precedence.if yes,is it right i need to convert that grammar in the form of operator precedence grammar?please tell me....

Comment: "if else statements, loops...etc" - those are control statements. Operator precedence usually applies to expression syntax. Can you show an excerpt of what your grammar looks like now and what you don't like about it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if you can change the operator precedence of a language through the grammar, then the answer is: yes, of course.

If you are asking if you can parse a "typical" context-free grammar using Pratt's method of top down operator parsing, then the answer is no. **BUT you can mix the two.** A good article covering Pratt parsing that should give you some info on applying this to a recursive descent parser: http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question, for which the answer is: yes. It appears as
a doubly-starred problem (#4.21) in Chapter Four of the Hopcroft & Ullman
text on Computability and Formal Languages. The answer (a summarized proof
by construction) is also provided.
Very briefly, it assumes pre-conversion to Reduced GNF, from which the final
construction is performed to remove adjacent non-terminals. Not the most
efficient construction, but it works (if you can follow the similar treatment
for conversion to CNF and GNF earlier).
Hope this helps!